# How to swap two dates in java

Tags: java

This is my code. What am I missing in it?

```
public class Date {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date dt[] = new Date[2];
          dt[0] = new Date(1,2,3);
          dt[1] = new Date(4,5,6);

        System.out.println("Before: "+dt[0]+" "+dt[1]);
        swap(dt[0],dt[1]);
        System.out.println("After: "+dt[0]+" "+dt[1]);
    }
    public void swap(Date dArr[]){
        Date temp ;
        temp = dArr[0];
        dArr[0]=dArr[1];
        dArr[1]=temp;
    }
}
```

input: d1 = 1/2/3   d2 = 4/5/6
output: d1 = 4/5/6  d2 = 1/2/3

Comment: What is the output of this program?

Comment: What does `Date` look like

Comment: The type of `swap` makes no sense: you pass it two `Date` objects, but the definition of `swap` you've given us takes an array.

Comment: Add the Date class code and check the params you are passing

Comment: It doesn't look like the implementation of `Date` should matter at all.

Comment: input: dates : d1=1/2/3      d2= 4/5/6   output: dates: d1 = 4/5/6   d2 = 1/2/3

Comment: You cannot call no-static method from static method ( i.e swap() method is non-static and main() method is static) you have to create the object and then you can call that method, or you can make the swap() method as static.

Answer (score 1):

```java
public void swap(Date dArr[]){
    Date temp ;
    temp = dArr[0];
    dArr[0]=dArr[1];
    dArr[1]=temp;
}
```

Your `swap` method takes  `[]Date` as an argument, and swap the first and second element of the given array.

Now, you call `swap` method like this:

```java
swap(dt[0],dt[1]);
```

You actually passed two `Date` object. The `swap` method creates an implicit `[]Date`  object as the input argument whose first element is `dt[0]` and second `dt[1]`. Note that this array of Date is not the same as your `Date dt[]`, they are independent of each other. You can think of `Date dArr[]` as containing two **pointers** to the `Date` objects in the old `Date dt[]`. When you call `dArr[0]=dArr[1];`, you just make the pointer point to another Date object, you can't affect the elements in `Date dt[]`.

If you want to change the original `Date dt[]`, you should pass **dt** itself as argument:

```java
swap(dt)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
package le9_ps1;
//import java.util.Date;

/* **********************************************************************  *
 *                           Exercise-9                                    *
 *   Objective: Pass parameters to methods - by value and by  reference.   *
 *                                                                         *
 *   Pre-condition: Date class should be created.                          *
 *   Problem Statement-1: Use the Date class created in Lab Ex1 to Swap two*
 *      Dates(Hint:use call by value method).                              *
 *  *********************************************************************  */


public class Date {
    int d,m,y;
    public Date(int dd, int mm, int yy) {
        this.d= dd;
        this.m = mm;
        this.y = yy;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date dt[] = new Date[2];
                dt[0] = new Date(1,2,3);
                dt[1] = new Date(4,5,6);

                System.out.println("Before: "+dt[0].d+"/"+dt[0].m+"/"+dt[0].y+ "  "+dt[1].d+"/"+dt[1].m+"/"+dt[1].y);
                dt=swap(dt);
                System.out.println("After: "+dt[0].d+"/"+dt[0].m+"/"+dt[0].y+ "  "+dt[1].d+"/"+dt[1].m+"/"+dt[1].y);
    }
    public static Date[] swap (Date dArr[]){
        Date temp ;
        temp = dArr[0];
        dArr[0]   =  dArr[1];
        dArr[1]  =   temp;
        return dArr;
    }
}

output:

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=1054:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Tukaram\Desktop\Exercise\ch3_le2\out\production\chapter4 le9_ps1.Date
Before: 1/2/3  4/5/6
After: 4/5/6  1/2/3

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Date {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date dt[] = new Date[2];
          dt[0] = new Date(1,2,3);
          dt[1] = new Date(4,5,6);

        System.out.println("Before: "+dt[0]+" "+dt[1]);
        dt = swap(dt);
        System.out.println("After: "+dt[0]+" "+dt[1]);
    }
    public static Date[] swap(Date dArr[]){
        Date temp ;
        temp = dArr[0];
        dArr[0]=dArr[1];
        dArr[1]=temp;
        return dArr;
    }
}
```

Comment: It throws error:-  java: non-static method swap(Date[]) cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Yes you can't call non static method from a static context so I made the ```swap function static``` error fixed

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use Collections to reverse the values?

```
List<Date> dates = Arrays.asList(new Date(1, 2, 3), new Date(4, 5, 6));
Collections.reverse(dates); // swaps the dates
```